# Why countifs combining criterion gives a different result than expected?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When countifs on `C:D` columns of `Yes` is 6 and countifs on `D:E` columns of `Yes` is 5, why countifs combining 2 criterion gives result as 4?

[image: Countifs]

Comment: Because it is `AND` not `OR`  So both have to be true at the same time.

Comment: @Jexgg, if you want `11` (6+5) then use this formula `=SUMPRODUCT((C3:D6="Yes")+(D3:E6="Yes"))` ☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Scott said in the comments, it's because [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) has to evaluate *all* conditions to `true`, not *any* (logical `AND`, not logical `OR`).

It goes through the ranges provided and checks if they match the criteria provided.  In your equation `COUNTIFS(C3:D6,"Yes",D3:E6,"Yes")` it performs the following 8 evaluations:

1. Is `C3` equal to "Yes" **and** `D3` equal to "Yes"?  Answer is no
2. Is `C4` equal to "Yes" **and** `D4` equal to "Yes"?  Answer is yes
3. Is `C5` equal to "Yes" **and** `D5` equal to "Yes"?  Answer is yes
4. Is `C6` equal to "Yes" **and** `D6` equal to "Yes"?  Answer is no
5. Is `D3` equal to "Yes" **and** `E3` equal to "Yes"?  Answer is no
6. Is `D4` equal to "Yes" **and** `E4` equal to "Yes"?  Answer is no
7. Is `D5` equal to "Yes" **and** `E5` equal to "Yes"?  Answer is yes
8. Is `D6` equal to "Yes" **and** `E6` equal to "Yes"?  Answer is yes

Using Venn diagram notation, you are looking at the *intersection* (or `AND`, first diagram), not *union* (or `OR`, second diagram):
[image: Venn diagram]

Comment: Maybe I didn't express properly in the question. I was not very clear about the meaning of =COUNTIFS(C3:D6, "Yes", D3:E6, "Yes"). Shouldn't it be counting when both C&D columns is "Yes" AND D&E columns is "Yes"? i.e. result is 1?

Comment: Just like when writing code =COUNTIFS(C3:C6, "Yes", D3:D6, "Yes", E3:E6, "Yes") I am counting on record with C,D,E columns are all "Yes", which result is 1.

Comment: No.  It is counting how many times a value inside 2x3 block of cells `C3:D6` is equal to "Yes" **and the same relative value** in the 2x3 block of cells `D3:E6` is equal to "Yes".  It's working them out in pairs (as per the list in the answer, `C4` **and** `D4` are both equal to yes, it's the first cell in both 2x3 blocks).

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and clarify.